# Why does a variable in my struct not hold its value?

Tags: go

If I have:

```
type Foo struct {
  bar int
}
```

And a method defined on Foo (notice it's not *Foo, just Foo):

```
func (self Foo)incrementBar() {
  self.bar++
}
```

Why after making a Foo and calling the method twice:

```
myFoo := Foo{}
myFoo.incrementBar()
myFoo.incrementBar()
```

is bar still 0 inside the incrementBar method every time myFoo calls it? i.e. it never gets to 2, each time I call incrementBar it does a ++ operation on the value 0.

Comment: Duplicate. The Tour of Go explains all this pretty well. Take it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use pointer method receiver since you're altering internal variables.
When you use non-pointer method receiver for `incrementBar`, an instance of `Foo` is copied and passed to `incrementBar`. Altering `self` in `incrementBar` does not change value of `myFoo` because it's merely a copy.

Here is a good article regarding the issue:
http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/08/09/dont-get-bitten-by-pointer-vs-non-pointer-method-receivers-in-golang/

Comment: But what if it's an inteface forcing me to not make it a pointer method receiver. The interface I have to adhere to requires my method be on Foo not *Foo.

Comment: @AndrewArrow interface won't enforce this. If you use pointer as receiver, then you could take it as **the pointer** implements the interface. So you pass `&Foo{}` instead of `Foo{}` around will do :)

Comment: I get: "GreenFoo does not implement ColorFoo (bar method has pointer receiver)"

Comment: oh, this explains it: http://jordanorelli.com/post/32665860244/how-to-use-interfaces-in-go